# JavaScript property access that throws an error

Tags: javascript, properties, runtime-error

In which specific cases does property access throw an error in JavaScript?

In Node.js, this prints `undefined`:

```
x = 3
console.log( x.thing );
```

This throws an error:

```
x = null;
console.log( x.thing );
```

What exactly is the semantics here? Property access is normal behavior for almost all values—even *functions*—but on `undefined` and `null` it throws an error.

I can't for the life of me find confirmation that those are the only cases. Can anybody confirm that?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `null.thing` to mean?

Comment: It's quite simple, when you try to look for a property of a number, it checks the numbers prototype. Had you done `x.toString` you would have seen that it's a function. However `null` is explicitly a lack of identification, indicating that a variable points to **no** object

Comment: I get all of that, I just don't know about other error cases. Are there any others?

Comment: `Property access is normal behavior for almost all values—even functions`, **No** this is wrong, in an object you can only access existing properties. For example in a string `str` you can only access existing properties such as `str.length` ... and properties that were not defined.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` and `null` are not references to objects, nor are they primitive values that can be implicitly boxed in object wrappers. Thus, any attempt to reference a property is going to fail.

When you use a number (`3`), the runtime boxes that as a Number instance, but of course there's no "thing" property so the value is `undefined`.

Also, functions are first-class objects, so references to properties on functions are not really "weird" in any sense.